# How does plus sign refers to plus function in Kotlin and is it an infix function?

Tags: kotlin, infix-notation

I have three questions.
1. how does plus sign *(+)* or *in* operator refer to *plus()* and *contains()* functions?
2. Are these infix functions?
They didn't have infix notation.
3. Is there any way that we can define custom characters as operators?

Comment: You should ask three separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) & 2)

`+` and `in` (and some others) are language built-in and are implicitly infix and have relevant operator functions (plus & contains).

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html#kotlin$plus(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Any)/other

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html

3) Yes, but you have to escape characters like this `` `$` `` or `` `^` ``

```kotlin
infix fun Int.`√`(arg: Double): Double {
    return Math.pow(arg, 1.0 / this.toDouble())
}

infix fun Double.`^^`(arg: Double): Double {
    return Math.pow(arg, this)
}

fun main() {
    println( 3   `√` 27.0 )   // 3.0
    println( 3.0 `^^` 3.0 )   // 27.0
}
```

Comment: @nikolai-shevchenko Thanks. so we need to use `` and we can't define custom operators like plus sign without `` ?

Comment: `+` and `in` are reserved keywords and are easily treated by compiler and don't need to be escaped, but custom operators do need to.

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloads are defined here

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

```
Expression  Translated to
a + b       a.plus(b)
a - b       a.minus(b)
a * b       a.times(b)
a / b       a.div(b)
a % b       a.rem(b), a.mod(b) (deprecated)
a..b        a.rangeTo(b)
```

Special symbols and reserved words are here

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html

> Operators and Special Symbols
>
> Kotlin supports the following operators and special symbols:
>
> +, -, *, /, % - mathematical operators

Comment: Thanks. I have read the documents before and I have been using Kotlin for a long time. What I don't know is that how did they define plus sign to be understood as plus() function!?

Comment: It's a reserved operator if I understand correctly, you can't make a mapping like that yourself outside the language.